# unable to change input color

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I added `var color` input (line 11-25) for enable input tab in the script. Input tab is added but color boxes in the input tab didn't work. When I change color, line color not changing [(screenshot)](https://i.postimg.cc/MTQsLHnC/input-tab.jpg).
Only the Style tab color boxes work [(screenshot)](https://i.postimg.cc/wMkkKmgG/style-tab.jpg).
I hope style tab items need to be look like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/q7CXJYpn/style-tab-real.jpg).
Please help.

```html
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © pbghosh

//@version=5
indicator(title='Daily CPR', shorttitle='D-CPR', overlay=true, format=format.price, precision=2)

blue = color.blue
fuchsia = color.fuchsia
white = color.white

var color_TC = input.color(defval=color.new(blue ,0), title='TC', group='CPR')
var color_CP = input.color(defval=color.new(fuchsia, 0), title='CP', group='CPR')
var color_BC = input.color(defval=color.new(blue, 0), title='BC', group='CPR')
var color_R1 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000,0), title='R1', group='CPR')
var color_R2 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000 ,0), title='R2', group='CPR')
var color_R3 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000, 0), title='R3', group='CPR')
var color_R4 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000, 0), title='R4', group='CPR')
var color_R5 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000,0), title='R5', group='CPR')
var color_S1 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000,0), title='S1', group='CPR')
var color_S2 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000, 0), title='S2', group='CPR')
var color_S3 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000, 0), title='S3', group='CPR')
var color_S4 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000,0), title='S4', group='CPR')
var color_S5 = input.color(defval=color.new(#FF4000,0), title='S5', group='CPR')
var color_PDH = input.color(defval=color.new(white, 0), title='PDH', group='CPR')
var color_PDL = input.color(defval=color.new(white, 0), title='PDL', group='CPR')


h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
c = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

showlabel = true
drawlabel(level, title, color) => label.delete(label.new(bar_index, level, title + " " + "(" + str.tostring(level, format.mintick) + ")", color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=color)[1])
        
notHigherTimeframe = timeframe.period != '30' and timeframe.period != '45' and timeframe.period != '60' and timeframe.period != '120' and timeframe.period != '180' and timeframe.period != '240' and timeframe.period != 'D' and timeframe.period != 'W' and timeframe.period != 'M'

calculatePivot() =>
    (h + l + c) / 3

calculateBC() =>
    (h + l) / 2

calculateTC() =>
    calculatePivot() - calculateBC() + calculatePivot()

truncate(number, decimals) =>
    factor = math.pow(10, decimals)
    int(number * factor) / factor
    //round(number * 10) / 10

pivot = calculatePivot()
tc = calculateTC()
bc = calculateBC()

if tc < bc
    t = tc
    tc := bc
    bc := t
    bc

r1Level = truncate(2 * pivot - l, 2)
r2Level = truncate(pivot + h - l, 2)
r3Level = truncate(h + 2 * (pivot - l), 2)
r4Level = truncate(h + 3 * (pivot - l), 2)
r5Level = truncate(h + 4 * (pivot - l), 2)
s1Level = truncate(2 * pivot - h, 2)
s2Level = truncate(pivot - (h - l), 2)
s3Level = truncate(l - 2 * (h - pivot), 2)
s4Level = truncate(l - 3 * (h - pivot), 2)
s5Level = truncate(l - 4 * (h - pivot), 2)

plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(tc, 2) : na, title='TC', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(pivot, 2) : na, title='CP', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.fuchsia, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(bc, 2) : na, title='BC', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r1Level : na, title='R1', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r2Level : na, title='R2', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r3Level : na, title='R3', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r4Level : na, title='R4', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r5Level : na, title='R5', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s1Level : na, title='S1', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s2Level : na, title='S2', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s3Level : na, title='S3', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s4Level : na, title='S4', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s5Level : na, title='S5', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? h : na, title='PDH', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.white, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? l : na, title='PDL', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.white, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)

if showlabel and timeframe.isintraday
    drawlabel(truncate(tc, 2), title='TC', color=color.blue)
    drawlabel(truncate(pivot, 2), title='CP', color=color.fuchsia)
    drawlabel(truncate(bc, 2), title='BC', color=color.blue)
    drawlabel(r1Level, title='R1', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(r2Level, title='R2', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(r3Level, title='R3', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(r4Level, title='R4', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(r5Level, title='R5', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s1Level, title='S1', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s2Level, title='S2', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s3Level, title='S3', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s4Level, title='S4', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s5Level, title='S5', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(h, title='PDH', color=color.white)
    drawlabel(l, title='PDL', color=color.white)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not using the input variables anywhere.

You need to replace the color values of the below lines with the input variables.

```
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(tc, 2) : na, title='TC', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(pivot, 2) : na, title='CP', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.fuchsia, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? truncate(bc, 2) : na, title='BC', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r1Level : na, title='R1', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r2Level : na, title='R2', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r3Level : na, title='R3', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r4Level : na, title='R4', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? r5Level : na, title='R5', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s1Level : na, title='S1', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s2Level : na, title='S2', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s3Level : na, title='S3', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s4Level : na, title='S4', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? s5Level : na, title='S5', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : #FF4000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? h : na, title='PDH', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.white, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(series=notHigherTimeframe ? l : na, title='PDL', color=pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color.white, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)

if showlabel and timeframe.isintraday
    drawlabel(truncate(tc, 2), title='TC', color=color.blue)
    drawlabel(truncate(pivot, 2), title='CP', color=color.fuchsia)
    drawlabel(truncate(bc, 2), title='BC', color=color.blue)
    drawlabel(r1Level, title='R1', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(r2Level, title='R2', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(r3Level, title='R3', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(r4Level, title='R4', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(r5Level, title='R5', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s1Level, title='S1', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s2Level, title='S2', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s3Level, title='S3', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s4Level, title='S4', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(s5Level, title='S5', color=#FF4000)
    drawlabel(h, title='PDH', color=color.white)
    drawlabel(l, title='PDL', color=color.white)
```

Comment: Input tab color box fixed. Why still style tab look like [this?](https://i.postimg.cc/j2rKMv6P/Untitled-1.jpg). Not like [this.](https://postlmg.cc/mcBFVmz2).

Comment: You don't have that much control over the style tab. The second example is that way because the colors depend on a condition. In your example, there is no conditional coloring. Therefore the user can change the colors via the style tab. If you want to prevent this, you can add `editable=false` to your `plot()`s.

Comment: adding `editable=false` will remove the other optons like line width and shape. we need the option for line width and shape. Here is the second [example](https://postlmg.cc/mcBFVmz2) script. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aTSQGIJOZzWk2gXeDOO4HoFxkRqASSrE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it a bug or else. Style tab color boxes - it's fixed when I merge it with other indicator.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This time it's expected behaviour, not a bug. Since your ADR script has more complicated logic with colors, the merged script lost the ability to change color via Style tab. Read more about it [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Colors.html#color-selection-through-script-settings)

Comment: if I didn't merge ADR script, there's no option to remove the colour box from the CPR script?

Comment: There is. If you read the link I gave you, you'd know all you need to do is to make the color logic more confusing... Take R1 in your code for example, the R1 plot color you have set to `pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color_R1` right? Change it to `color.new(pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? na : color_R1, 0)` will make the color picker disappear.

Comment: Fixed. But, there's a black merging line between pervious days. How do we remove that? [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/05SYsm2L/Untitled-1.jpg)

Comment: Change it to `color.new(color_R1, pivot[1] != pivot and notHigherTimeframe ? 100 : 0)` instead.

Comment: Thanks vitruvius & tentme. All fixed in this question.